# Symfony 6 can't send email with mailer (without configured database)

Tags: database, symfony, configuration, mailer

Hello guys i just started to building web using Symfony6 - im trying to send email using mailer however it somehow require database to be configured (+ some special table created for messages...).Maybe there is some workaround so it would work without DB.. - thing is in Symfony 5 there was no problem with that.

Comment: Use composer to remove the doctrine migration bundle.  You can always add it back later if you decide to use a database.  If that does not fix the problem then consider updating your question with the relevant part of your error message.  Mind reading is fun but there are limits.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you comment the default configuration in config/packages/messenger.yaml

`#Symfony\Component\Mailer\Messenger\SendEmailMessage: async`

or set it to null your email should be sent immediately.

Comment: That was exactly the thing ! ;] thx (but that conf is in config/packages/messenger.yaml)

Answer (score 4):

By default it's configured to work in async mode via messenger, that's why @glukose 's answer works. It sets sync mode and emails are sent immediately that way.

Your messenger is configured to work via Doctrine, that's why it requires DB. Like this:
`MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN=doctrine://default`

You can use many [other options](https://symfony.com/doc/6.0/messenger.html#messenger-transports-config), like Redis or AMQP, async mode is used for a reason after all.

Anyway async mode won't work without workers started with command `php bin/console messenger:consume async`. That was my problem because I wasn't aware about *what* was used. No errors, but emails are not actually sent with Symfony mailer!