# Symfony 6 mailer with "An exception occurred in the driver: could not find driver" problem

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, mailer

I'm trying to make a contact form with Symfony and Mailer. I think I've missed something in the configuration part but I don't know what.

Here is the mailer part in my **.env** :

```
###> symfony/mailer ###
MAILER_DSN=smtp://localhost:1025
###< symfony/mailer ###
```

My submitted form part in my **ContactController.php** :

```
if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

    $contactFormData = $form->getData();
        
    $message = (new Email())
        ->from($contactFormData['mail'])
        ->to('XXXX@gmail.com')
        ->subject('Envoi depuis la page Contact par '.$contactFormData['name'])
        ->text($contactFormData['message']);
    $mailer->send($message);

    $this->addFlash('success', 'Your message has been sent');

    return $this->redirectToRoute('app_contact');
}
```

And I got this error message :

[image]

Can you tell me, what I'm doing wrong ?
Noé

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71569745/1706130

Answer (score 0):

First configure a transport server for mailer.

For clear reference, read the docs provided by symfony carefully

https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html

Comment: Yeah, that's what I've done now. I've made an account in SendGrid, run `composer require symfony/sendgrid-mailer`, and then configure `MAILER_DSN`in my .env file; but it still doesn't work... In the doc, they said "If your credentials contain special characters, you must URL-encode them." Do you know how can I make this ?